# Simple Form: Is it possible to remove labels and replace them with placeholders using the labels i18n?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, simple-form

I'm trying to produce a regular simpleform form

```
= simple_form_for [:hq, @team, @order] do |f|
  .tickets
    = f.select :tickets, :aaa => "aaa"
    = render "ticket"


  .details
    .left
      = f.input :address1
      = f.input :address2
      = f.input :state
      = f.input :country
      = f.input :email
    .right
      = f.input :comments
```

But I want the inputs to not be rendered with a label, just the title "Address Line 1" in the placeholder.

I know I can do this with `f.input :address1, :placeholder => "whatever", :label => ""` but I'd like it to be configurable with a wrapper and take the i18n value form label, not placeholder.

Comment: use :label => false and not :label => "", the latter will still generate a label tag in the DOM.

Comment: I think [this][1] is the answer you're looking for.


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/a/18199780/186145

Answer (score 23):

Try doing the following:

```
f.input :address1, placeholder: "Address Line 1", label: false
```

Answer (score -2):

If you want to use javascript, here is a jQuery snippet that does the job:

```
$.each($(".left .input"), function() {
  var label = $("label",$(this)).text();
  $("label",$(this)).hide();
  $("input",$(this)).attr("placeholder",label);
});
```

The main advantage using js for this case is that the result remains screen-readers compliant (they will read the label because they won't run the js).

Comment: I disagree with this. There are ways to accomplish this within simple form and without javascript.

Comment: @Senjai old comment i know, but could you go into further details or link about how you might do this instead?

Comment: Apologies ignore this solution was via the duplicate link above, see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18077082/how-to-use-placeholders-instead-of-labels-in-simple-form/18199780#18199780)